# How do you call a partial view in a modal div,and passing an object parameter to it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I have a problem concerning a modal  (bootstrap) I want to open. I want to include a partial view.
(I am boing to post my code in a few minutes).

Here is the objective : 
1- I have an Index.cshtml page where a link call a javascript

```
<div class="profile-userbuttons">

@Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", "Profil", null, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-success"@*, id = Model.userLog*@ })

</div>
```

(Note that I have commented the second (id) parameter in my anonymous type).
(This parameter should be a object of type userLog).

Then a click on this link call a javascript script :

```
<!-- Calling Modals -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Initialize numeric spinner input boxes
        //$(".numeric-spinner").spinedit();
        // Initialize modal dialog
        // attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
        // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.

        alert(1);
        $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(2);
            $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
            $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
            alert(3);
        });
        // Attach listener to .modal-close-btn's so that when the button is pressed the modal dialog disappears
        $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });
        //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
        $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });
        $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And of course, the modal div is present in the Index.cshtml :

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade"
         tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Remark that the modal is empty. My script is in charge of filling it.

But lets return to my ActionLink. the Action link target a Action : "Edit", in my Controller "Profil"

Here it is :

```
 public ActionResult Edit(/*userslog id*/)
        {
            return PartialView("Edit"/*,id*/);
        }
```

(I have commented the parameter, to test it was a "parameter passing" issue).

As you read it you see it should return a partial view named "Edit".

here it is :

```
@model WebSiteModels.Models.userslog

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <h2>Edit</h2>

        <h3>YO !</h3>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>userslog</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.photo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prenom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prenom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sex, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sex, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sex, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telephone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.adresse, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.adresse, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.adresse, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lattitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lattitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lattitude, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.longitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.longitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.longitude, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idpersonne, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idpersonne, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idpersonne, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idcontact, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idcontact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idcontact, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateModification, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateModification, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateModification, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button type="submit" id="approve-btn"
                        class="btn btn-danger">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#approve-btn').click(function () {
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And when I test it, here is the capture screen I obtain :

[Capture screen result : modal seems to be called, but in the browser console, is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjnly.png)

So here is my problem. My partial view is not called despite the modal is opened. Moreover, when I open it in the browser : every thing appears well. 
What do I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to fill the modal content using JQuery with something like(see NEW LINE):

```
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(2);
        **//// NEW LINE
        $(".modal-content").load("/Profil/Edit");
        ////**
        alert(3);
    });
```

and convert the Html.ActionLink to simple `<a class='modal-link' data-target='#modal-container' data-toggle='modal'></a>` tag with same attributes.

Comment: Hi Arun ! sorry to answer that late, but I am not at home these days ! I'll test your proposition when I'll be back ! (i think you got it !)